# Increment through an array once the counter hits a certain value

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a method that moves one space up in the `mSize` array once the method is invoked (counted through the `meals` variable).

```
 class Dog {

    String mSize[] = {"tiny", "small", "average", "large"};

    int dogSize;

    int meals;


    final float WEIGHT_GAIN = 0.25f;

    float mWeight;

    /*
         * feed
         *
         * Feeds the Dog.
         *
         * Side-effect: 1. The Dog gains weight, specifically WEIGHT_GAIN
         *              2. Every 3 meals, the Dog grows to a larger size, if
         *                 possible
         *                 i.e. "tiny" (3 meals later ->) "small" (3 meals later ->)
         *                 "average" (3 meals later ->) "large"
         *                 the Dog cannot exceed the "large" size or shrink smaller than
         *                 "tiny"
         * @return nothing
         */ 

    void feed(){
    mWeight += WEIGHT_GAIN;
    if (++meals == 3 && getSize()!= mSize[mSize.length-1]){

   dogSize ++;
   getSize();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

`meals` had to be a member variable, and I wasn't using the `getSize` method, which returns `mSize[dogSize]` Not sure if I should be using `setSize` somewhere either.

```
 /*
     * getSize
     *
     * @return the size of the dog (String)
     */
    /************************************************
     *  ASSIGNMENT:
     *  Create the getSize method
    /************************************************/
String getSize(){
    return mSize[dogSize];
}
    /*
     * setSize
     *
     * Sets the size of the Dog
     *
     * @param size the new size of the Dog (String)
     * @return nothing
     */
    /************************************************
     *  ASSIGNMENT:
     *  Create the setSize method
    /************************************************/
void setSize(String size){
    mSize[dogSize] = size;
}
```

Test in the main method:

```
// Test feed
        try {
            float weight = (Float) getWeight.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            if (((Float) getWeight.invoke(dog, new Object[0])) <= weight) {
                System.out.println("Your Dog should have gained some weight");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            if (!"average".equals(getSize.invoke(dog, new Object[0]))) {
                System.out.println("Your Dog didn't grow to average after 3 meals :(");
                System.exit(1);     
            }
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            if (!"large".equals(getSize.invoke(dog, new Object[0]))) {
                System.out.println("Your Dog didn't grow to large after 3 more meals :(");
                System.exit(1);     
            }

            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            feed.invoke(dog, new Object[0]);
            if (!"large".equals(getSize.invoke(dog, new Object[0]))) {
                System.out.println("Your Dog should stay large if it keeps feeding like this");
                System.exit(1);     
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong with " + feed.getName());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `mWeight` and `dogSize`?

Comment: The while loop seems out of place to me... Should he really be eating so many meals per one feed? I would've thought the controller would have to call feed 3 times, then he would have grown a size

Comment: `mWeight` is a member variable, but it didn't relate to the problem at hand so I didn't put it in there. But since it's in the method I added it in, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like

```
class Dog {
    static String mSize[] = { "tiny", "small", "average", "large" };
    int dogSize = 0;
    int meals = 0;

    void feed() {
        if (++meals % 3 == 0) {
            dogSize++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Weight = %.2f, Meals = %d, Size = %s",
                meals / 3.0, meals, mSize[dogSize]);
    }
}
```

And then to test it, something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog d = new Dog();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        System.out.println(d);
        d.feed();
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Weight = 0.00, Meals = 0, Size = tiny
Weight = 0.33, Meals = 1, Size = tiny
Weight = 0.67, Meals = 2, Size = tiny
Weight = 1.00, Meals = 3, Size = small
Weight = 1.33, Meals = 4, Size = small
Weight = 1.67, Meals = 5, Size = small
Weight = 2.00, Meals = 6, Size = average
Weight = 2.33, Meals = 7, Size = average
Weight = 2.67, Meals = 8, Size = average
Weight = 3.00, Meals = 9, Size = large
Weight = 3.33, Meals = 10, Size = large
Weight = 3.67, Meals = 11, Size = large
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in the feed method and changed `meals` and `dogsize` to be initialized class variables, but the test method (that has been already written in another class) is still showing that it's not working.

Comment: It might be useful for us to see the test method as well? Could be somewhere there, or otherwise update your question to have the latest Dog code

Comment: Hi, I updated the code and put the test method there just in case. It's still not working, but I'm pretty sure the `feed()` method is solid as it is, it's just a question of implementing the other ones.

Comment: @silentkit Please post enough of your test method that we can run it. You might even make that a new question around your use of [reflection](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html), because we can't run it as is.